# Spring Boot AutoConfiguration - bean creation order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have and application which use JPA.

For reasons which are beyond this question I'm providing custom `JPAVendorAdapter` in separate static configuration class. And the configuration behaves non-deterministic.

On my Windows deksktop when I enable `--debug` I see expected result:

> JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all)
>   found the following [customJPAVendorAdapter] (OnBeanCondition)

But as soon as I deploy the application to some server I get:

> JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all)
>   found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

The code is definitely the same.

Please is there a way how to tell that my `@Bean` with `JPAVendorAdapter`must be created before `JpaBaseConfiguration` kicks in and auto-configure the default adapter?

**Edit:**

The configuration is pretty spread but hopefully I'll cover the main parts:

**Main config:**

```
@ComponentScan(
        value = {"module.package"}
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaBaseConfiguration.class
    })
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MainConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements SchedulingConfigurer {
 ...
}
```

**The module using JPA:**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Conditional(value = SelfHelpConfig.ModuleCondition.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SelfHelpModuleComponentScanPlaceholder.class)
public class SelfHelpConfig {

    public static class ModuleCondition extends AbstractModuleEnabledCondition {

        @Override
        public String getModuleId() {
            return "self-help";
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Conditional(value = SelfHelpConfig.ModuleCondition.class)
    static class JpaVendorConfig {

        @Bean
        public AbstractJpaVendorAdapter customJPAVendorAdapter(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProviderWithNamingStrategy jpaPersistenceProvider) {
            log.info("Creating custom JPA vendor adapter");

            return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
                @Override
                public PersistenceProvider getPersistenceProvider() {
                    return jpaPersistenceProvider;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And this modules `@ComponentScan` discovers the DB config:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = SelfHelpModuleComponentScanPlaceholder.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = SelfHelpModuleComponentScanPlaceholder.class)
@Import({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DBConfig {

}
```

If the JPAVendorConfig is not placed in separate class it's not applied at all. if in separate class then it works on my desktop but not when deployed to Linux server.

Comment: Post your configuration...

Comment: First why do you have the condition twice and why nest a config in a config, adding it as a bean to the out config should work as well. But do you really need this, what is so special about this adapter that you need a customized provided? Looks to me you can get the same by setting the appropriate properties instead and is this making things more complex.

Comment: As explained if not nested it doesn't work at all. Once nested works "sometimes". I need to add custom prefix to a table per environment. I.e. achieve something like `@Table(name = "${prefix}_myTable")`

Comment: Then why not simply register a custom `NamingStrategy` that is simply configurable via `application.properties`? Instead of trying to do it with conditionals. You still shouldn't need to double check on the condition (only on the nested one should be enough) but only a single configuration class with the conditional on the bean method should work as well.

Comment: Naming strategy takes a class not a bean so you can't inject properties into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88195/discussion-between-jan-zyka-and-m-deinum).

Comment: The conditional is there for different reason ... NamingStrategy doesn't work as it takes class name so you can't inject properties into it. You would need naming strategy per environment (which is probably an option though)

Comment: Well you can create a static variable which you can set in your naming strategy. So while you might not be able to create an instance, you can still do a sort of workaround which is easier imho then trying to create a class per environment and try to get it to work. This would only work if you have a single entity manager though...

Comment: Will give it a shot, that didn't really came to m y mind, it's hacky but probably less hacky than what I did before.

Comment: You could also create an extension of the `LocalContainerEntitiyManagerFactory`, implement the `postProcess` method, get the hibernate classes, the service registry and manually register the instantiated `NamingStrategy`, which would allow you to register a spring configured one. Although not sure if that might already be too late.

Comment: You made me find the right path. I tried the static thing but there was no clear point where to set the static variable. Every place where I was able to inject the property via Spring was too late. I created separate `NamingStrategy` for each environment. I found it cleanest by far. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.